# Connect to Facebook chat using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, xmpp

I'd like to make a bot that periodically logs into facebook's chat network and stores snapshots of the roster. I'm aiming for a dataset that can tell me which of my friends are online when / how often as a demonstration of the privacy risks of facebook.

Is there a library I can use to connect to Facebook's XMPP chat network using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Jabber PHP client classes you can glean from:

http://www.google.com/search?q=php+jabber

Comment: I've worked through class.jabber.php, xmpphp and jabber_class.php but can't get any of them to correctly connect to facebook's chat. Am I missing something>?

Comment: Jordan could you please provide some information on how did u achieved this .. i need facebook chat api for PHP

Comment: [This](https://github.com/shadow-fox/facebook-jaxl/blob/master/facebookChat.php) works for me.