# Facebook chat/messenger integration php

Tags: php, facebook, chat

I am clearing my doubt here, 
Can I integrate Facebook chat/messenger with my PHP application? I found that the API is deprecated on April 30th 2015 , is there any new API available from facebook? I am asking for facebook's own API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to Facebook chat using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746083/connect-to-facebook-chat-using-php)

Comment: No I am asking for facebook's own API ? is there anything?

Comment: No there is no new API

Comment: @WizKid Thank you , Thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1):

@Rajith R., **On April 30, 2014, Facebook developers announced the deprecation of the XMPP Chat API as part of the release of Platform API v2.0.**

[Refer this article about the deprecated Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat)

Comment: Ok , that I Know, anything new? or not possible now? I need that answer.

Comment: that is all there is to know.